# Angular: different keycloak grant types depending on the URL

Tags: angular, keycloak

I have a Angular webap that currently asks users to authenticate interactively. Here is my code:

```
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

const initializeKeycloak = (keycloak: KeycloakService) => async () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: kcUrl,
        realm: kcRealm,
        clientId: kcClient,
      },
      initOptions: {
        flow: 'hybrid',
      },
      shouldAddToken: (_request) => true
    }).then(async (authenticated) => {
      if (authenticated) {
        bearerToken.next(await keycloak.getToken());
      }});

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: /* some imports  ... */,
    providers: [KeycloakService,
      {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
        multi: true,
        deps: [KeycloakService]
```

Now I need the same webapp, when opened by means of the `/kiosk` URL, to authenticate using the `client_credentials` grant type (no user interaction).

I looked at both the keycloak-angular and keycloak-js docs, but I couldn't find anything about how to implement the client credentials grant.

Do the keycloak-angular and keycloak-js modules support such a configuration? If yes, how do I enable it for the `/kiosk` URL only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coding the thing myself. I still do not know whether keycloak-angular and keycloak-js support the `client_credentials` grant, but the required code is short and simple enough to avoid caring for external libraries: I added a custom guard for the `/kiosk` url, which obtains the token from keycloak.

Here is the relevant snippet of code for others, just in case:

```
  async getClientCredentialsGrantToken(kcClientId: string, kcClientSecret: string): Promise<Response> {
    const data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('client_id', kcClientId);
    data.append('client_secret', kcClientSecret);
    data.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');

    return fetch('https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'omit',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      redirect: 'follow',
      body: data,
    });
  }
```